# Visual Studio 2019 won't stage added files to a Git repo

Tags: git, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2019 I add files to a Project in a Solution by either by A) in Solution Explorer using the right-click menu on the Project -> Add -> Existing Item and selecting files, or B)  dragging those files from Windows Explorer to that Project in Solution Explorer. In either case I can't find a way to add those files to the Project's/Soution's Git repository. The Git Changes tab doesn't "see" those files at all, even though the .voxproj file is shown to be modified and committable. How do I add existing programming/text files to a Visual Studio 2019 Project and then add those files to the Git repo Visual Studio 2019 creates/manages for that Project in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: Have you checked the .gitignore file to see if those files have been marked to ignore?

Comment: Yes. .cc files are not in .gitgnore, Nor these specific .cc files (ie main.cc)

Comment: Manually adding the files to the repo by dragging and dropping them into the repo folder in Windows Explorer dose work. Both the Solution Explorer and Git Changes "see" the files when I do this.

Comment: Can you open a terminal in the project directory and try to do add unstaged files by CLI using `git add .`?

Comment: No, doesn't work. Git is not installed outside of Visual Studio 2019 on this computer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have figured it out. The Visual Studio Solutions Explorer is completely divorced from the underlying file system. If you move it in Visual Studio, it DOSN'T move in the directories. So if I want a file to be included in the Git repo I have to move it there manually.